# What is the howling noise from the roof bars when driving at speed?

Tags: noise

I have some square roof bars, but whenever I drive along at 40mph+ there is a loud howling noise coming from them. It isn't just my car, as whenever I remove them the noise disappears.

This also happens in a friends car with square roof bars.

These are what I am talking about (not roof rails!):

[image]

Why do they make this noise?

Is there anything I can do? Removing the bars is a pain as I cannot store them anywhere in the car when driving along...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whistling is one of the main defects of Square Roof Bars , what you can do is install something called as **windjammers** which are nothing but sheet of metal/plastic which acts as a wind deflectors and makes the bars more aerodynamic.

[image]

some examples are [http://www.amazon.com/Yakima-8001115-WindJammer/dp/B0012SDZZG](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0012SDZZG)

Also what you can do is tie some ropes across the bars which might rupture the constant flow of air causing the whistling noise but then it makes the car look odd and are not as good as ready-made wind deflectors as seen above.

Answer (score 0):

Mine make a whistling noise, as far as I am aware it is caused by the air passing around them. Mine have a slot underneath which probably doesn't help.